# Vim update plugins with errors

Tags: python, macos, vim

Now i update my .vimrc in Mac Osx but i have the next errors:

> Error detected while processing /Users/dmuino/.vimrc: line   59: E319:
>   Sorry, the command is not available in this version:  py << EOF line
>   60: E492: Not an editor command:  import os line   61: E492: Not an
>   editor command:  import sys line   62: E15: Invalid expression:
>   'VIRTUAL_ENV' in os.environ: line  117: E171: Missing :endif

But i checked my .vimrc but i don't find any error in it, could you help me?
My .vimrc is the next:

```
set nocompatible              " required
filetype off                  " required
 set runtimepath+=~/.vim_runtime
 source ~/.vim_runtime/vimrcs/basic.vim
 source ~/.vim_runtime/vimrcs/filetypes.vim
 source ~/.vim_runtime/vimrcs/plugins_config.vim
 source ~/.vim_runtime/vimrcs/extended.vim
 set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
 set splitbelow
 set splitright
 call vundle#begin()
 "split navigations
 nnoremap <C-J> <C-W><C-J>
 nnoremap <C-K> <C-W><C-K>
 nnoremap <C-L> <C-W><C-L>
 nnoremap <C-H> <C-W><C-H>
 " Enable folding
 set foldmethod=indent
 set foldlevel=99
 " Enable folding with the spacebar
 nnoremap <space> za
 " alternatively, pass a path where Vundle should install plugins
 "call vundle#begin('~/some/path/here')

 " let Vundle manage Vundle, required
 Plugin 'gmarik/Vundle.vim'
 Plugin 'tmhedberg/SimpylFold'
 Helptags

 let g:SimplyFold_docstring_preview=1
 " PEP8 indetantion
 au BufNewFile,BufRead *.py
    \ set tabstop=4
    \ set softtabstop=4
    \ set shiftwidth=4
    \ set textwidth=79
    \ set expandtab
    \ set autoindent
    \ set fileformat=unix
 " HTML, JS, CSS indentation
 au BufNewfile,BufRead *.js, *.html, *.css
    \ set tabstop=2
    \ set softtabstop=2
    \ set shiftwidth=2
 "Fix problem indentation PEP8
 Plugin 'vim-scripts/indentpython.vim'
 "Uneccesary whitespace
 au BufRead,BufNewfile *.py,*.pyw,*.c,*.h match BadWhitespace /\s\+$/
 " UTF8 support
 set encoding=utf-8
 "Autocomplete
 Bundle 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe'

 let g:ymc_autoclose_preview_window_after_completion=1
 map <leader>g :YcmCompleter GoToDefinitionElseDeclaration<CR>

 " python with virtualenv support

 py << EOF
 import os
 import sys
 if 'VIRTUAL_ENV' in os.environ:
     project_base_dir = os.environ['VIRTUAL_ENV']
     activate_this = os.path.join(project_base_dir, 'bin/activate_this.py')
     execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))
 EOF

 " Syntax Checkin/Highlighting
 Plugin 'vim-syntastic/syntastic'
 Plugin 'nvie/vim-flake8'
 let python_highlight_all=1
 syntax on

 "Color Shemes
 Plugin 'jnurmin/Zenburn'
 Plugin 'altercation/vim-colors-solarized'
 if has('gui_running')
     set background=dark
     colorscheme solarized
 else
     colorscheme zenburn
 endif
 call togglebg#map("<F5>")
 "File Browsing
 Plugin 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
 Plugin 'jistr/vim-nerdtree-tabs'
 let NERDTreeIgnore=['\.pyc$','\~$'] "Ignore files in NERDTree

 "SuperSearching
 Plugin 'kien/ctrlp.vim'
 "Line numering
 set nu
 "Git integration
 Plugin 'tpope/vim-fugitive'

 "Powerline
 Plugin 'Lokaltog/powerline', {'rtp': 'powerline/bindings/vim/'}

 "System clipboard
 set clipboard=unnamed
 "VIM in the shell
 set editing-mode vi

 " add all your plugins here (note older versions of Vundle
 " used Bundle instead of Plugin)

 " ...

 " All of your Plugins must be added before the following line
 call vundle#end()            " required
 filetype plugin indent on    " required

try
source ~/.vim_runtime/my_configs.vim
catch
endtry
```

Comment: What do you mean "i don't find any error in it"? Vim is complaining about specific lines in your `vimrc` and those lines are obviously there. Your Vim is apparently not built with Python support so either wrap your Python snippet in a check or install a proper Vim built with Python support.

Comment: Although not immediately related to your problem, your `~/.vim_runtime/…` seems fishy.

Comment: install a vim that has `+python` enabled at build time.

Comment: I install the latest version of vim from the github, but the error is the same. What do i do to change the support for python in build time?

Answer (score 6):

change

```
 " python with virtualenv support

 py << EOF
```

to

```
" python with virtualenv support
py3 3
py3 << EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message clearly points to your `~/.vimrc`, at line 59:

```
" python with virtualenv support

py << EOF
[...]
```

Your Vim configuration assumes a Vim with built-in support for the embedded Python interpreter (`:py` command). You can make your `~/.vimrc` more robust by adding a defensive check. Usually this is done with `exists()` (e.g. `if exists(':python') == 2`), but for the embedded interpreters, the check usually is done via `if has('python')`.

If you need that customization, you have to use a Vim version that has support for Python built-in. How to obtain such depends heavily on your system, the way you install software. In the worst case (no packages available), you'd have to install all source code dependencies and compile Vim on your own. But I think that for MacOS X, this isn't necessary...